# gulpfile.jsでのgulp.src()で特定のディレクトリを無視する方法について

Tags: gulp

こんにちは。

gulp-sftpを使い、gulp.srcで指定したディレクトリをアップロードしようとしています。
1つずつ指定するのは冗長になるため、アップロードが不要なディレクトリにはプレフィックスとしてアンダースコア`_`をつけました。
そこで、`gulp.src(["**/*", "!_*/**/*"])`という記述をしました。
しかし、これでは２階層目以降の`_`から始まるディレクトリが無視されませんでした。
全階層で`_`から始まるディレクトリを無視するにはどのように指定したら良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。